# How can I make an interactive line graph through Shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

## Problem

I'm new to Shiny, so apologies if I'm way off on this. I'm trying to make an interactive line graph through Shiny so a country can be chosen through drop down list, and then an accompanying line graph can show how suicides/100k people within that country have changed from 1987 to 2015. It looks like I have the Input portion correct, but I am struggling with coding the appropriate output plot. More specifically, I am unsure of where to introduce the reactivity portion of this (where do I put the input$country?).

## Data Structure (only first 3 rows)

```
|year| |age group| |country  | |Suicides Per Age Group Per 100K Population|
|----| |---------| |---------| |------------------------------------------|
|1987| |5 - 14   | |Argentina| |.47                                       |
|1987| |5 - 14   | |Australia| |.28                                       |
|1987| |5 - 14   | |Austria  | |.44                                       |
```

## My current code

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(selectInput(inputId = "country", 
                            label = "Choose a Country", 
                            choices = data$country[!duplicated(data$country)]), # list of non-duplicated countries
                plotOutput("line"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$line <- renderPlot({ggplot(dash_plot_data, 
                                    aes(year, 
                                        `Suicides Per Age Group Per 100K Population`, 
                                        color = age, group = age,
                                        aes())) + 
      geom_line()
  })
}

# View App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Again, I'm not sure where to insert the input$country portion. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "country", 
               label = "Choose a Country", 
                choices = unique(data$Country)), 
                plotOutput("line")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$line <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data %>% filter(Country == input$country), 
           aes(year, `Suicides Per Age Group Per 100K Population`, 
          color = age, group = age)) + geom_line()
  })
}
```